# Redefining method in `Enumerable`

Tags: ruby

If I redefine a method in `Enumerable`, for example

```
module Enumerable
  def map
    "hello"
  end
end
```

I thought then `map` in `Array` will be changed to my version. But `[1,2,3].map {|x| x+x}` still outputs `[2,4,8]`. I checked the manual of `Array`, and there is no `map` defined, there is only `map!`. How can I make `Array` use my `map` method? Is redefining
Array the only way?

Comment: `Array.instance_method(:map).owner #⇒ Array < Object` :: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-map

Comment: @mudasobwa +1 for the `#owner` method, didn't know about it before, thanks

Comment: You may wonder why there is a method `Array#map`. Why not just have `[1,2,3].map ...` use `Enumerable#map`?  And it's not just `map`; several  classes that `include Enumerable` have methods with the same names as Enumerable methods.  There are two main reasons for this. Firstly, in some cases a more efficient algorithm can be used by tailoring the method to a particular class.  Secondly, some of those methods in classes behave differently than their cousins in `Enumumable`. An example is [Hash#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-select), which returns a hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mudasobwa points out, `Enumerable#map` is overridden by `Array#map`. Redefining `Array#map` is one way to do it. Another way is to create a new module, and prepend that to `Array`.

```
module MyEnumerable
  def map
    "hello"
  end
end
class Array
  prepend MyEnumerable
end
```

Comment: I checked the pickaxe book, map is not under Array (and collect). Does that mean the pickaxe book is not giving the complete reference?

Comment: If what you wrote is true, then it is not complete, or is only true for older versions of Ruby.